# How to measure python-asyncio in python3.7

Tags: python, performance-testing, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I want to caculate python asyncio performance and select only cpu time cost.

I have read [how-to-measure-pythons-asyncio-code-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826533/how-to-measure-pythons-asyncio-code-performance/34827291).

But asyncio.Task._step was changed to private which wrote into [c modules](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/5293)

```
import asyncio
print(asyncio.Task)  # _asyncio.Task

print(dir(asyncio.Task))
['__await__', '__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', 
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
'__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', 
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', 
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_asyncio_future_blocking', '_callbacks', '_coro', 
'_exception', '_fut_waiter', '_log_destroy_pending', '_log_traceback', '_loop', 
'_must_cancel', '_repr_info', '_result', '_source_traceback', '_state', 'add_done_callback', 
'all_tasks', 'cancel', 'cancelled', 'current_task', 'done', 'exception', 'get_loop', 
'get_stack', 'print_stack', 'remove_done_callback', 'result', 'set_exception', 'set_result']
```

I can't hack to use only py-code because I don't want to lose c code performance.

Comment: Why not use standard tools like [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix))? Also see my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34827291/2846140) :)

Comment: If you aren't doing something very special, you don't need to measure CPU time cost. What you really want is to make sure some coroutine doesn't block event loop for too long. To achieve it use [debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38857440/1113207) of event loop. No warnings will mean everything is ok and CPU takes much less time than network I/O.

Comment: @Vincent time.process_time is good but it is not great enough in coroutine. When I use asyncio.gather the process time is not correct which will be affect by the other jobs. While the old way in Python3.6 is good because it only calculate muiti step in own task.

Comment: @tianjunma That makes sense. It's pretty hackish but I guess you could [patch asyncio handles](https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/fc394d139218ebbfd1b775ae392b26ec).

Comment: @Vincent Wheather is it safe, inherit from asyncio.tasks._PyTask to create a TimedTask factory?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be simple and useful,

```py
import time

def time_this(func, *args, **kwargs):
    st = time.process_time()
    func(*args, **kwargs)
    return time.process_time() - st
```

Below's an example,

```
In [1]: import time, asyncio
   ...: 
   ...: def time_this(func, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:     st = time.process_time()
   ...:     func(*args, **kwargs)
   ...:     return time.process_time() - st
   ...: 
   ...: print(time_this(asyncio.run, asyncio.sleep(5)))
0.001157819000000007
```

###### Update #1:

Or you could follow [this](https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/620eb3a02d97d3da9dacdc508a5d5321) approach, writing your own event loop policy.