# How to measure execution time of an aync query/request inside Kotlin coroutines

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have a microservice on which I am using Kotlin coroutines to perform a bunch of db queries asynchronously, and I want to monitor the execution time for each one of those queries for potential performance optimization.

The implementation I have is like this:

```
val requestSemaphore = Semaphore(5)
val baseProductsNos = productRepository.getAllBaseProductsNos()
runBlocking {
    baseProductsNos
        .chunked(500)
        .map { batchOfProductNos ->
            launch {
                requestSemaphore.withPermit {
                    val rawBaseProducts = async {
                        productRepository.getBaseProducts(batchOfProductNos)
                    }

                    val mediaCall = async {
                        productRepository.getProductMedia(batchOfProductNos)
                    }

                    val productDimensions = async {
                        productRepository.getProductDimensions(batchOfProductNos)
                    }

                    val allowedCountries = async {
                        productRepository.getProductNosInCountries(batchOfProductNos, countriesList)
                    }

                    val variants = async {
                        productRepository.getProductVariants(batchOfProductNos)
                    }

                    // here I wait for all the results and then some processing on thm
                }
            }
        }.joinAll()
}
```

As you can see I use Semaphore to limit the number of parallel jobs, and all the repository methods are suspendable and those are the ones I want to measure the execution time for. Here is an example of an implementation inside ProductRepository:

```
  suspend fun getBaseProducts(baseProductNos: List<String>): List<RawBaseProduct> =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      namedParameterJdbcTemplateMercator.query(
        getSqlFromResource(baseProductSql),
        getNamedParametersForBaseProductNos(baseProductNos),
        RawBaseProductRowMapper()
      )
    }
```

And to do that I tried this :

```
      val rawBaseProductsCall = async {
        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val result = productRepository.getBaseProducts(productNos)

        val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        logger.info("${TemporaryLog("call-duration", "rawBaseProductsCall", endTime - startTime)}")

        result
      }
```

But this measurement always returns inconsistent results for the average in contrast to the sequential implementation(without coroutines), and the only explanation I can come up with is that this measurement includes the suspension time, and obviously I am only interested in the time that the queries take to execute without a suspension time if there was any.

I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible in Kotlin, but it looks like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826533/how-to-measure-pythons-asyncio-code-performance) supports this. So I will appreciate any help to do something similar in Kotlin.

**UPDATE:**

In my case I am using a regular java library to query the db, so my DB queries are just regular blocking calls which means that the way I am measuring time right now is correct.

The assumption I made in the question would have been valid if I was using some implementation of [R2DBC](https://r2dbc.io/) for querying my DB.

Comment: What does your code do _except_ suspend here?  Just create the RPC and parse the result?

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes that is what it does, and I wait for the results from the queries then I do some processing on them. I am not sure if I answered your question?

Comment: So are you just trying to measure the time of creating the RPC and parsing the result?  The time the server spends answering your RPC?

Comment: yes exactly that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: But... you are measuring on the client (your microservice acts as client for the DB coroutines). Unless you have more insight on the server, what else would you go for?

Comment: Sorry @HiranChaudhuri I don't get what you mean, but my problem is that the coroutine may not resume execution right after the query response is received because the treads are occupied or the maximum parallel jobs are reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not want to measure the coroutine startup or suspension time so you need to measure over a block of code that will not suspend, ie.. your database calls from a java library

stdlib for example provides a few nice functions like `measureTimedValue`

```
val (result, duration) = measureTimedValue {
    doWork()
    // eg: productRepository.getBaseProducts(batchOfProductNos)
}
logger.info("operation took $duration")
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.time/measure-timed-value.html

Comment: Correct order is: (result, duration), not (duration, result)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is intentional or by a mistake, but you use only a single thread here. You start tens or even hundreds of coroutines and they all fight each other for this single thread. If you perform any CPU-intensive processing in "here I wait for all the results and then some processing on thm" then while it is working, all other coroutines have to wait to be resumed from `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. If you want to utilize multiple threads, replace `runBlocking {}` with `runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {}`.

Still, it doesn't fix the problem, but rather lessens its impact. Regarding the proper fix: if you need to measure the time spent in the IO only then... measure the time in the IO only. Just move your measurements inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` and I think results will be closer to what you expect. Otherwise, it is like measuring the size of a room by standing outside the building.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, yes I am aware that the other code will run on the same thread, and for the time measurement, I also tried what you suggested but the results were pretty much the same.

Comment: Hmm, so if you put everything inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}` and it still provided unexpected results then I can't find a good explanation for this. Assuming all functions inside this block (`query()`, `getSqlFromResource()`, etc.) are not suspendable (are they?), coroutines should not really affect execution of this code in any way. This is just a regular blocking code.

Comment: `query()` is from an external java library and it is the actual query so I don't know how Kotlin will handle it, but normally this is the only place where the code could be suspended since the other functions are not suspendable. are you saying that the coroutine won't suspend the code inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}`?

Comment: Only suspend functions can suspend. If `query()` is from some Java library, then I guess it is not really a suspend function, but a regular blocking one. If we put regular, blocking code inside a suspend function, then this block of code will/should execute just normal, as if there would be no coroutines at all.

Comment: If that is the case then the recorded time is correct, because right now I have almost triple the time recorded in sequential calls. could it be because of concurrency the DB is taking that much time?

Comment: I can only guess. I don't know your backend, how it was implemented, etc. If you can't control the backend to add measurements there, then maybe you can at least read its logs to get some insights about the performance. As a last resort, you can try to capture the network traffic, but if you need to calculate the average from multiple requests then it would pretty hard to do